# How to add two subdomains as exceptions from WordPress' wilcard redirects?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, wildcard

The hosting company I'm with has completely destroyed my .htaccess file about a month ago and while I managed to make most of it work again, I do not know how to add two exceptions to WordPress' wildcard subdomains (I use WordPress multisite). The hosting company is refusing to help me and, as a plain old web designer, I am not that good with rewrite rules and the server stuff and I never was.

This is the file - where do I add exceptions for approved.iva-is.me and love.iva-is.me?

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line:

```
# skip these 2 hosts
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(approved|love)\.iva-is\.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Sadly, nothing is happening. I added them where you suggested it and I still get redirected to the main domain.

Comment: 1. Try this in a new browser. 2. Open firebug and then open your page to see what you get in Net tab.

Comment: Thanks for offering more help. I use Chrome more than Firefox and here is what the Network tab outputs, assuming the top two lines are relevant: [link](http://i.imgur.com/bkM058N.png)

Comment: Hmm I see a 302 happening before which shouldn't happen as per this rule. Are you sure this is placed in root .htaccess as **first rule**

Comment: Sure. The rest of the file contains only WP Total Cache rules. I just looked at the Subdomains section on my cPanel and I see no redirections of any kind.

Comment: That probably explains. Looks like that plugin is caching this.

Comment: I removed the plugin and nothing has changed. I will give it some more time and try to flush DNS.

Comment: It turned out the hosting company did not restart the server after updating it. Your solution was correct, but could not take effect before a friend logged in as me and did what was needed to be done.